# How to calculate delta array for a cumulated array in a performant way using JSONata?

Tags: jsonata

I am having a json structure consisting of an array of 253 location objects.  Each location object has an array reporting the cumulated total over time (array having 67 elements).

I would like to extend each location object in the json structure with an array (delta array) that is reporting the increase based on the cumulated total array.

The following json query is correctly doing this task:

```
(
    covid ~> | locations | { 
        "new_total" : $map(cumulated_total, function($v, $i, $a) {$a[$i]-($i=0 ? 0 : $a[$i-1])}) 
        } |;
)
```

The problem with that query is that it takes about 66 seconds to execute on my intel NUC device.

The JSONata Exerciser link containing an example of the json input structure together with the query I have used:

- https://try.jsonata.org/BGqIUkWe7

Note that when I open that link it is reporting `Expression evaluation timeout: Check for infinite loop` because the query also takes too long to execute in my JSONata Exerciser window.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it makes much difference, but you could try pulling the function definition up to the top level so that it only gets done once (since you're not relying on any lexical context in the function body):

```
(
    $fn := function($v, $i, $a) {$v-($i=0 ? 0 : $a[$i-1])};
    covid ~> | locations | { 
        "new_total" : $map(cumulated_total, $fn) 
        } |;
)
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this.  I just checked it and moving the function definition up to the top doesn't make a noticeable difference.

Comment: I have pinpointed the problem to the retrieval of `$a[$i-1]` in the function: this took about 44 sec of the 48 sec total time.  Note also that replacing `$a[$i-1]` by `$a[$i]` reduced the time with 28 sec (so more than halved the total time).

Answer (score 0):

Following query is more performant (47 sec total time).  So this is 19 sec more performant compared to query in the original post (66 sec total time).

```
(
    covid ~> | locations | { 
        "new_total" : $map(cumulated_total, function($v, $i, $a) {$v-($i=0 ? 0 : $a[$i-1])}) 
        } |;
)
```

As you can see I have only changed `$a[$i]` by `$v` in the function code.

Comment: Note that if I remove `-($i=0 ? 0 : $a[$i-1])` from the function code then the query is executed in 1 sec.  So it is really this part of the function code that is very expensive.

Comment: When using this function `function($v, $i, $a) {$v -($i=0 ? 0 :-1)}` I am also getting a response within 2 or 3 sec.

Comment: Following function `function($v, $i, $a) {$a[$i-1]}` gave a response within 44 sec.
So the retrieval of  `$a[$i-1]` is the most expense part of the query (44 sec of a total time of 48 sec).

Comment: Following function `function($v, $i, $a) {$a[$i]}` gave a response within 16 sec.  So this is considerably faster compared to  `$a[$i-1]` which took 44 sec.